How can I modify minecraft region files to place blocks in specific locations
I want to create a program that will take a list of blocks and co-ordinates and then generate a minecraft world that has all those blocks placed at the given co-ordinates.
The world data is stored in .mca files but I don't know how to read it.
Using a program called NBTExplorer I can open the file but even then I don't understand how it's storing the world. I still don't understand how I can modify it to place a block at a specific location.
The file isn't Gzipped, and I don't think it's using Zlib either.
Does anyone know how I can decompress the file, or how to modify it to set specific blocks once it's in a readable format?

The region file format is complicated, especially for blocks. It uses something called a "palette" that lists all the types and then references that in the part that corresponds to the block grid. There are libraries for dealing with these files for a couple programming languages, e.g. Python.

The "palette" is more akin to the color atlas in  a JPEG (if you know anything about compressed formats)

Documentation at https://minecraft.wiki/w/Anvil_file_format
